# directadmin/exim not delivering email from phpsendmail to (same) google apps domain

Tags: magento, google-apps, exim

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while.

We use Magento. And it sends order emails to customers from the address contact@domain.com through php sendmail. A BCC or separate email is sent (as a copy) to contact@domain.com

The customer receives the email. But the BCC or separate email to contact@domain.com never arrives in our google apps account (sent from contact@domain.com to contact@domain.com).

Help appreciated.

Sean

---

We followed this
http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=8

Even this shell command does not reach the contact@domain.com emailbox

```
echo "Test" | mail -s "Test" contact@domain.com
```

**exim bt output**

```
[domain@vpsxxxx ~]$ exim -bt contact@domain.com
contact@domain.com
  router = lookuphost, transport = remote_smtp
  host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com      [2a00:1450:4008:c01::1a] MX=10
  host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com      [74.125.136.26]          MX=10
  host ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4008:c01::1b] MX=20
  host ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [74.125.143.27]          MX=20
  host ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [173.194.69.26]          MX=20
  host ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.com   [74.125.25.26]           MX=30
  host ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com   [173.194.64.26]          MX=30
```

Log records from main log

```
2014-01-25 17:08:26 1W75mT-0004xJ-L9 => contact@domain.com F=<user1@vpsxxxxxx.public.cloudvps.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=580 H=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4008:c01::1a] X=UNKNOWN:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1390666106 k2si7548786bkr.9 - gsmtp"
2014-01-25 17:09:47 1W75nn-0004yi-At <= domain@vpsxxxxxx.public.cloudvps.com U=domain P=local S=537 T="Test" from <domain@vpsxxxxxx.public.cloudvps.com> for contact@domain.com
2014-01-25 17:09:47 1W75nn-0004yi-At => contact@domain.com F=<domain@vpsxxxxxx.public.cloudvps.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=555 H=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4008:c01::1a] X=UNKNOWN:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1390666187 om1si7503738bkb.219 - gsmtp"
```

Comment: Find the log entries for a complete send attempt and add it to the post, otherwise we can't really guess at what is going wrong.

Comment: jep. done .... .......

Answer (score 0):

I found this sollution, which works for all my clients!

2. Login as admin
3. Click Show all Users
4. Find the user that owns the domain
5. Click that user
6. Click Modify User
7. Make sure DNS Control is checked and Save
8. Click Home and Repeat 2-4
9. Click Login as
10. Click the domain if there is more than one. If only one skip this step.
11. Click MX records
12. Uncheck "Use this server to handle my emails" which is under the "Local Mail Server" section.

[image]